# Internet Explorer 11: MouseUp triggered on Scrollbar-MouseDown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, windows-10

To workaround a problem that a scrollbar-click caused an onBlur-Event I used "mousedown" to flag the click as "inside" my div and on mouseup I would reset the flag.

I'm not sure since when (an update?) this behaviour doesn't work anymore. I've created a fiddle to demonstrate this:

http://jsfiddle.net/30x1jr6v/1/

```
$(document).mousedown(function (documentEventObject) {
    console.log('mousedown');
});
$(document).mouseup(function (documentEventObject) {
    console.log('mouseup');
});
```

If you use chrome, the mouseup event fires, when you release the mouse-button on the scrollbar. In IE 11, the mouseup event fires together with the mousedown event... Did anyone experience the same problem?

Versions:

- Internet Explorer 11.0.10240.16431, Updateversion: 11.0.22 (KB3078071)
- Windows 10

Interestingly I also have a Windows 7 Laptop with IE 11.0.9600.18059 installed. There I only get the mousedown message in console (no mouseup even when I release the button)!

Comment: Nope, in IE11 I only get the mousedown event on the scrollbar, but not the mouseup event when releasing.

Comment: Really? What exact version do you have? I'll Update my question with my version... I tested in on another machine with the same behaviour - both are running Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue (not losing focus of my input when the scrollbar is clicked) with a timer instead of the mouseup:

```
var mouseDownWasInMyDiv = false;

$(myDiv).mousedown(function () {
  mouseDownWasInMyDiv = true;
  setTimeout(function() {
    mouseDownWasInMyDiv = false;
  }, 0);
});

$(myInput).blur(function () {
  if (mouseDownWasInMyDiv) {
    mouseDownWasInMyDiv = false; // should be set in Timeout but can also happen without click (e.g. TAB)
    refocus();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your comment here, for formatting.

- IE 11.0.9600.18015C0 Update 11.0.23
- Windows 7 Enterprise

I'm at work and couldn't test your fiddle, so used this instead.  Same behavior on every version of JQuery...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
$(document).mousedown(function (documentEventObject) {
    console.log('mousedown');
});
$(document).mouseup(function (documentEventObject) {
    console.log('mouseup');
});
</script>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />
```

Comment: I tested your script by making an html-File and opening it with Chrome and IE11 and making the window so small that the scrollbars appear. And the result is the same as in my question: On Chrome I get mousedown/mouseup separately - on IE I get mousedown&mouseup on mousedown click.